# Function to resize array not working [C]

Tags: c, arrays, resize

This is a program for studying purposes.
I'm trying to increment an array size while the program is running, until its size is equal to 12. But i'm getting an error and i don't know why. Will appreciate your help.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void incrementSize(int **arr, int *currentSize);
void swap(int **a, int **b);

void main() {
    int i = 0,
        size = 3;
    int *array = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    while (size < 12) {
        if (i == size) //If the logical size is equal to the physical size increment the size of the array.
            incrementSize(&array, &size);

        array[i] = i + 1;
        i++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) //Prints the array
        printf("%d ", array[j]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I wrote this function to increment the size of a given array and returns the new size.

```
void incrementSize(int **arr, int *currentSize)
{
    int newSize = 2 * (*currentSize);
    int *tmpArr = realloc(*arr, newSize * sizeof(int));

    if (!tmpArr)
    //If the allocation didn't work
    {
        printf("ERROR. Memory reallocation failed!");
        free(tmpArr);
    }
    else
    //If it worked swap the addresses of "tmpArr" and "arr" and then free "tmpArr"
    {
        swap(arr, &tmpArr);
        free(tmpArr);
        *currentSize *= 2;
    }
}
```

and also wrote this function to swap the addresses of two given arrays

```
void swap(int **a, int **b)
{
    int* tmp;
    tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

Comment: in C, you shouldn't cast the return of malloc.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Just an error without any specifics

Comment: There is no such a thing.

Comment: compile with the -g flag set, and run it through a debugger and maybe valgrind, and let us know the errors.

Comment: i ran it through a debugger and then it gives me this error "ConsoleApplication9.exe has triggered a breakpoint."

Comment: So it is stopped on breakpoint, cool. Now run it step by step.

Comment: i ran it step by step and i could see that the first realloc worked and then the second didn't

Comment: Just a question, why do you need the "swap" thing? you are discarding the `tmpArr` anyway.

Comment: BTW, it is your problem. You are freeing something that was re-allocated and now sitting int `tmpArr`. You don't have too (actually you can't). Just assign it back to `*arr` and you are done.

Comment: because i want to free the initial address of "arr" (which i pass on to "tmpArr") after i change its address to the address of "tmpArr".

Comment: No, you don't want to free it. It is exactly where it is failing. `realloc` is taking care of it.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`realloc` actually `free`s storage  pointed by given pointer.

If there is not enough memory, the old memory block is not freed and
null pointer is returned.

If argument is NULL, the behavior is the same as calling `malloc(new_size)`.

Code you wrote would `free` already `free`d memory.